# Subsetting different length strings by spaces in R

Tags: r, string, date, subset

In R, I currently have a long vector of dates and times saved as a string. So depending on the given date, the string can be 16 or 17 or 18 characters long and so I cannot just subset the first the 8 or 10 characters in the string, since that would not work for every date. But since there is a space between the date and time values, I am wondering how can I subset this string so that I only get the characters before the space?

Just to show how the string looks like now, here are a couple of examples:

- "4/18/1950 0:00:00"
- "6/8/1951 0:00:00"
- "11/15/1951 0:00:00"

Comment: Try `sub(' .*', '', x1)` to get the date part or just `as.Date(x1, '%m/%d/%Y')`.  It may be better to keep this as 'Date' class instead of the character string you originally have.  In case, you need the original use  `format(as.Date(x1, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')`, now the `nchar` will be the same for all the 3 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are familiar with regular expressions, if not you should learn as they are extremely useful:
[tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.regular-expressions.info%2Ftutorial.html&ei=E0gMVYDAOdGmyATDnYGYBg&usg=AFQjCNEi0GPwTIIpInTqQDV_5xK1ozYsAg&sig2=b0W451WCiao0ynAHhyFsrg&bvm=bv.88528373,d.aWw)

As akrun pointed out you can use the "sub" command to remove the space and everything after it like this:

`sub(" .*","",stringVar)`

- First argument is the regular expression code which matches the space and everything that follows.
- Second argument is what you want to replace the match with, in this case nothing
- Third argument is the input string

Alternatively, you can just split the string at the space and select the first half using "strsplit"

`strsplit(stringVar," ")[1]`

Comment: Whoops sorry, I have edited to point out that you mentioned that solution first.